# Saving PNG plot non-ggplot in Shiny

Tags: r, download, png, shiny

I'm trying to download a non-ggplot file in Shiny. I can see the plot in the app, but when I click the plotDownload button in UI, it download an EMPTY png file. Someone can have idea what I'm doing wrong??

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(
   function(input, output) {

      plotInput <- reactive({
        plot(rnorm(sample(100:1000,1)))
      })

      output$pngPlot <- renderPlot({ plotInput() })


      output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "myPlot.png",
        content = function(file){
          png(file, width=800, res=100)
          print(plotInput())
          dev.off()
        })    
  }
)
```

**ui.R**

```
require(shiny)
pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Output to png"),
  sidebarPanel(
    downloadButton('downloadPlot')
  ),
  mainPanel({ mainPanel(plotOutput("pngPlot")) })
)
```

Thnks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replot within the downloadHandler():

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    plotInput <- reactive({
      plot(rnorm(sample(100:1000,1)))
    })

    output$pngPlot <- renderPlot({ plotInput() })


    output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "myPlot.png",
      content = function(file){
        png(file, width=800, res=100)
        plot(rnorm(sample(100:1000,1)))
        dev.off()

        })    
  }
)
```